# Changing default "dropdown icon" on Semantic-UI

Tags: css, meteor, semantic-ui

As in subject, I am trying to change the default "dropdown icon" in semantics ui when implementing an accordion in a meteor-based environment, but I have no clue on how and where to start. I would like to keep its default behaviour (i.e. when clicked it rotates 90 or 180 degrees) and not to simply change the icon with a code like:

```
    <div class="title">
        <i class="new icon"></i>
    </div>
```

The code I put actually changes the icon but does not keep the default behaviour of rotating 180 degrees.
Any clue on how to do it? Semantic CSS looks complicated to me, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if the icon according to your example has the class "new" add this to your css:

```
.ui.accordion .active.title .new.icon,
.ui.accordion .accordion .active.title .new.icon {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.ui.accordion.menu .item .active.title > .new.icon {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```